# ffmpeg and grep not working to extract mean_volume value

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg

I have a list of mp3 files and i want to set all `mean_volume` to the same db value using a script, so I enter the command for detecting the value (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioVolume) and I try to `grep` the value but it fails and instead prints all the output from the `ffmpeg` command. Any thoughts?
Also tried `tr` instead of `grep`. The command I used is:

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mp3 -filter:a volumedetect -f null /dev/null | grep 'mean_volume'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ffmpeg` console output is stderr, so you need to redirect to stdout:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter:a volumedetect -f null - 2>&1 | grep mean_volume
```

or for Bash 4+:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter:a volumedetect -f null - |& grep mean_volume
```

Result:

```
 [Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x564635d62800] mean_volume: -22.6 dB
```

If you just want the value use `awk`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter:a volumedetect -f null - |& awk -F': ' '/mean_volume/ {print $2}'
```

Result:

```
-22.6 dB
```